# Filling out multiple values with Cinema 4D

Tags: cinema4d

I have a pretty simple question that does not seem to be showing up anywhere. I am have been watching a lot of C4D tutorials lately and many times people are zeroing out an object or scaling it up which in both cases requires the user to fill out 3 axis value fields with the same number. To do this they select the X value, fill it in, then the Y value, fill it in then the Z value and fill it in, which seems very tedious. Is there a way to select all three fields and type in just one value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first click enter the desired value to one of the fields. Right Click and select Copy. Then just ctrl+click on the names of the fields you want to change or click the left suffix of the group of fields and Right-click Paste.

For example the S.X , S.Y, S.Z has the left suffix S and the right X , Y , Z. Clicking on the left suffix will select all three parameters. Clicking the right suffix enables for individual selections.